# Is there way to get the original url name of the file that I upload on s3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I currently new on doing storing multiple files on s3 bucket using the laravel. Right now I already coded some of function to store the files. The main problem that I encounter is every time i return the file it always shows the tmp file. In the tutorial that I watched right now is different to the output that i return.To understand well I will shows some pictures.

**Question:** Why does my output return tmp filename?

**My Output:**

[image: My Output]

**Tutorial Output:**

[image: tutorial output]

**My Function:**

```
        $file_upload = $request->file('files');

        foreach($file_upload as $file) {

            $file->store('bucket','s3');

            // Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($file,'public');

            $store_file = File::create([
                'filename' => basename($file),
                'url' => Storage::disk('s3')->url($file)
            ]);

        }
        
     
       
        return $store_file;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the return value of `store()` and not the `UploadedFile` when storing the filename and url in your database:

```
$file_upload = $request->file('files');

foreach ($file_upload as $file) {
    $path = $file->store('bucket', 's3');

    $store_file = File::create([
        'filename' => basename($path),
        'url' => Storage::disk('s3')->url($path)
    ]);
}

return $store_file;
```

PS:

Your return statement does not make much sense, currently when you upload more than one image, it will only return the last uploaded one instead of all of them, since you are overwriting `$store_file` with each iteration.